# Google Extended Trends API for Health in python

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-api-python-client, google-trends

I have access to the Trends API. I am trying to run the `getTimelinesForHealth` API. Doesn't seem to execute. I am running the code in Python.

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/trends/v1beta/timelinesForHealth? key=MY_API_KEY&geoRestriction.country=US&terms=cold&terms=cough&time.endDate=201 2-01-01&alt=json&time.startDate=2011-01-01&timelineResolution=week returned "Daily Limit Exceeded">

We tried this on 2 different computers. Cookies are enabled. The daily limit is definitely not exceeding we are sure about that. (This is mentioned since some posts suggested to try out these alternatives)

Nevertheless, when I am using the `getGraph()` API that executes very well. So, this is something peculiar only about the timeline for health API.