# HttpError 400:Bad request when accessing Google Extended Trends API for Health

Tags: python, json, google-api

I have received permission to use the private Google Extended Trends API for Health for research.
I want to train myself to use the tool, so started out by simply implementing the sample python code in the Google Extended Trends API for Health-Getting Started Guide.pdf file which Google provided.
To my mind, this code should work. If I get that working, I can start modifying it to create my own requests. If I get it working...

I am using Python 3.6.3

I see a similar post here:
[Google Extended Trends API for Health in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613401/google-extended-trends-api-for-health-in-python)
But they got no answers.

This is the full traceback I get when running the code:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Google trends\Google Trends_Health API\Google Trends Sample Code.py", line 156, in  main()

File "C:\Google trends\Google Trends_Health API\Google Trends Sample Code.py", line 142, in main frequency= 'day')

File "C:\Google trends\Google Trends_Health API\Google Trends Sample Code.py", line 104, in GetQueryVolumes res = req.execute ()

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\oauth2client_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 839, in execute

raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/trends/v1beta/timelinesForHealth?terms=flu&terms=cough&time.startDate=2011-01-01&time.endDate=2015-01-01&timelineResolution=day&geoRestriction.region=US-MA&key={Yeah, like I'd show that here!}&alt=json returned "Bad Request">

I see in the traceback that it is calling the helpers.py module from the OAuth folder, so was wondering about this: [400 (Bad Request) when requesting GA API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032474/400-bad-request-when-requesting-ga-api)
but the guide says that: "Note: You do not need OAuth2 for this API."

I can also see on my dashboard that the request is registering, so it must be something to do with the actual formatting of the JSON request. I'm no expert on JSON, so I may need help with that.
The request, pulled out from above is:
https://www.googleapis.com/trends/v1beta/timelinesForHealth?terms=flu&terms=cough&time.startDate=2011-01-01&time.endDate=2015-01-01&timelineResolution=day&geoRestriction.region=US-MA&key=APIKEY&alt=json

Any clues as to what is going wrong? I tried changing the API version from v1beta and that gave me a specific error for the wrong version name, so it's not the version name that's at fault.
I can't seem to find any definitive answers for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around, I realised that the json string is well-formulated, it was rather just a matter of the API not wanting to give that resolution (day) for that time frame. I shortened the time frame to time.startDate=2015-01-01&time.endDate=2015-12-31 and it worked.
I suppose a bit of a guide for the API methods might have helped.
Nonetheless, I should be able to figure out what I can and cannot do with some trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing pretty much the same issue right now. I think the culprit in the sample code is that it asks for too many data points at once (i.e., greater than 2,000, which is the current limit). Data points is calculated as `number of terms * time * resolution`. So when you changed the time frame, the number of requested data points went down, and the call went through.

Hope this helps future users!